Android Talkback issue for ImageView
I'm using ImageView for voiceover accessibility as below:
imageView.setContentDescription("This is ImageView control");
But problem which I'm facing, that voiceOver pronouncing complete sentence as "This is imageview control, ImageView"
I want to suppress the last word "ImageView" from voiceover, but could not get any solution. Can anyone help on this please?

You should not override this behaviour in Android, it's known as the Role or type, and it helps Screen reader users know what kind of node they are currently focussed on, and how they could potentially interact with it.
From Android's documentation:

Don't include the type of UI element in the content description. Screen readers automatically announce both the element's type and description. For example, if selecting a button causes a "submit" action to occur in your app, make the button's description "Submit", not "Submit button".

So part of good app citizenship is letting this role stand as part of the announcement.
Additionally, you now do not need to add redundant content descriptions like "Image(View) Of" since users can control that kind of thing from the screen reader settings.
Also I think you mean TalkBack, not VoiceOver.

